# Load balancer causing errors 'failed to load resource'

Tags: http, nginx, load-balancing

I have an application running on 3 servers and nginx-based load balancer in front of them.

When I don't use the load balancer, and request for the individual application, everything works well. But with the load balancer, I am not able to use my application in its best way. In my browser console, I am getting errors like 'Failed to load resource' and 'You have exceeded your request quota for this API'.

What are the possible causes of this and how to resolve them?

Nginx conf file for load balancer:

```
upstream Load_Balance{
    server server1:443;
    server server2:443;
    server server3:443;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://Load_Balance;
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using https on your backend?

Comment: yes. I am using https on my server1/2/3.

Comment: from point of view this config is weird, because you using http->https.